# Strict container border in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, components, containers

I put some components to Group container, but I can move them outside container border and see them. How I can do the components could not be seen outside?
For example: 100*100 container, put into them simple button and setup (x,y) = (150, 150). So, button in container, but seen outside. I want to border of my container be a real border and hide outside components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do, is set the Group's [clipAndEnableScrolling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#clipAndEnableScrolling) property to `true` (it is `false` by default).

```
<s:Group width="100" height="100" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">  
    <s:Image width="150" height="150" 
             source="@Embed(source='/gfx/myimage.jpg')"/> 
</s:Group>
```

Here's some more documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS8DF44A60-B4B0-491f-A359-1B193DEB18D6.html